# I can`t get my head around channels and goroutines. When to finish thread?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I am trying to create some concurrent pipeline for API calls. Let's say I want to have just 2 threads running the requests in the same time and a repeat on error.

I've come up with this minimal example: https://go.dev/play/p/JzkjXW_dTj5

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

const THREADS = 2

func main() {
    arguments := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

    channel := make(chan int, THREADS)

    go writeChannel(channel, arguments)

    for i := 0; i < THREADS; i++ {
        go doWork(channel)
    }

    fmt.Scanln()
}

func writeChannel(channel chan<- int, arr []int) {
    for _, arg := range arr {
        channel <- arg
        fmt.Println("sent:", arg)
    }
}

func doWork(channel chan int) {
    for {
        argument := <-channel

        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3) //Simulate work

        error := rand.Intn(2) == 0 //Simulate error
        if error {
            fmt.Println("error, repeat:", argument)
            go repeatWork(channel, argument)
            continue
        }

        fmt.Println("finished:", argument)
    }
}

func repeatWork(channel chan<- int, argument int) {
    channel <- argument
}
```

I can add some more channels to save the response, add some more threads to save it and see when the last call is successfully saved, just wanted to keep the example minimal. My main concern is that doWork() lasts forever waiting for arguments to come. Can I somehow cancel it instead? Maybe I just should create more channels and finish the doWork() on finish? Or maybe there's just different approach to such problem?

I have tried to figure this on my own, couldn't really find any article about this problem.

Comment: Heeey so it looks like what I was looking for is Worker thread pool. http://marcio.io/2015/07/handling-1-million-requests-per-minute-with-golang/